# SQL Server placement of master database files vs resource database files

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

In a post on [SqlServerCentral.com](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/best-practices-for-the-system-databases), it is mentioned by several people that the files for the Resource database (mssqlsystemresource.mdf and ldf) should be placed in the same folder as the master database file. This was for SQL Server 2005. Is this still a recommendation when it comes to SQL Server 2017? I tried looking in BOL, but could not find any mention of this there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Totally agree with what George has mentioned, just trying to shed some more light to make it clear.

**For SQL Server 2005**

You were allowed to move resource database. If you read [SQL Server 2005 Master Database Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms187837(v=sql.90)) it says

> The Resource database depends on the location of the master database. If you move the master database, you must also move the Resource database to the same location.

But this caused problem during service pack upgrade when users started moving it along with master database. The issue came while applying SP/CU which eventually failed because resource database was moved.

**For SQL Server 2008 and above.**

This was then fixed by MS and they changed the whole thing such that "user is not allowed to change resource database location" and this is why it was moved to 
`<drive>:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL<version>.<instance_name>\MSSQL\Binn`folder along with other binaries, people normally do not touch contents of BINN folder. It's specifically in BINN folder because it does not contains any USER data only information related to SQL Server.

Yes there was some discrepancy in BOL documents which was later fixed. I wrote an article on this please read [Should We Move Resource Database](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29828.sql-server-should-we-move-the-resource-database.aspx)

Moral: Do not move resource database

Answer (score 4):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/resource-database?view=sql-server-2017)

> changing the location of the resource database is not supported or recommended.

It would also appear that a static path is produced for the location of the resource database in the form of

```
<drive>:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL<version>.<instance_name>\MSSQL\Binn\
```

It would appear there is neither a supported path to change the locations of the resource database files, nor is it recommended to do so.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that as well (maybe should have said so in my post), but in the link there is mentioned a way to move it (from BOL they say), that is why I got a bit worried. We also have an instance where the two are located in different folders and have been so for years without any problems, but I don't think we have tried upgrading inplace for such a setup. (And that is when the problems will arise according to the link.)

Comment: George. Your answer was helpful, but the one from Shanky was a bit more explanatory (if that is a word), so I change the accepted answer to his.

Comment: @GHauan absolutely no problem with that - I would suggest in future potentially make your question a bit clearer? IMO I answered the question directly.

Comment: You are right, my bad. Thank you for taking the time to answer.